# JS: Traversing the DOM to push in elements to an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to traverse the DOM and push all the `li` nodes to an array but I'm having a problem with my loop.

Given this piece of html:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="section">
       <div>
           <ul>
              <li>Test1</li>
              <li>Test2</li>
           </ul>
           <div> 
              <div>fake test</div>
              <ul>
                <li>Test3</li>
                <li>Test4</li>    
              </ul>           
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="section">

   </div>
   <div class="section">
      <div>
         <ul>
           <li>Test5</li>
           <li>Test6</li>  
          </ul>             
      </div>
   </div>
   <ul>
       <li>Test7</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

I am grabbing the `container`:

```
let container = document.querySelector('.container');

function traverseDOM(node, arr=[]) {
     
    if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
        [...node.children].forEach(childNode => {
           traverseDOM(childNode,arr);
        })
    } else {
         if (node.nodeName == "LI") {
            arr.push(node)
         }
    }
}
```

I know the issue is that this wouldn't keep running after it hit the else condition.  I'm not sure how exactly to fix it so that I could keep it running ...or if this would even be the proper way to traverse it.

Comment: What is this line for `let container = document.querySelector('.container');` ?

Comment: starting node to give the function `traverseDOM`

Comment: Why don't you use `someAppContainer.querySelectorAll("li")` ? And there you go, you have a NodeList of all the LI in that parent? Or is this an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  ...I mean, sure.  If this were a real world scenario, I'd probably do that and call it day.  I am trying to practice traversing the DOM though.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `NodeList` is never *live*. `HTMLCollection` can be.

Comment: @connexo https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-536297177

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan https://dev.to/jharteaga/difference-between-htmlcollection-and-nodelist-25bp There are both *static* NodeLists (e.g. what querySelectorAll returns) and *live* NodeLists (e.g. element.childNodes). What you suggested is returns a static NodeList.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems quite simple:

```js
if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
} else {
   // else? Well, nothing to push here than
}
```

Therefore:

```js
function traverseDOM(node, arr = []) {
  [...node.children].forEach(node => {
    if (node.nodeName == "LI") arr.push(node)
    traverseDOM(node, arr);
  });
  return arr;
}

const LIs = traverseDOM(document.querySelector('.container'));
console.log(LIs);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Test1</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
      </ul>
      <div>
        <div>fake test</div>
        <ul>
          <li>Test3</li>
          <li>Test4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section">
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>Test5</li>
        <li>Test6</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>Test7</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also, there's no explicit need to do `node.hasChildNodes()` but you can keep it for eventual perf reasons.